# i used the virtualenv venv command after installing django in my desired folder faced an error how to resolve this

Tags: python, django

```
D:\django>virtualenv venv
Using base prefix'c:\\users\\admin\\programs\\python\\python37'
New python executable in D:\django\venv\Scripts\python.exe
ERROR:the executable D:\django\venv\Scripts\python.exe is not functioning
```

It says the program cant start because `VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing` from my computer. How do I reinstall and fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling Microsoft Visual C++.

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/vcruntime140-dll-is-missing

Answer (score 0):

I think this Documentation will be helpful for you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/windows/
you can find all installation guidelines here.
Thanks.
Good Luck